# Maximum number of concurrent Server-Sent event connections on Netty

Tags: netty, spring-webflux

When using Spring 5's Webflux, and a Netty application server, it's possible to send Server-Sent Events to users. In case of unlimited CPU, Bandwidth and RAM, what is the factor that defines the maximum number of concurrent users though?

Comment: The number of people on earth? If done "right", this should be CPU-bound and you should see latency degradation at some point (hopefully around 80% CPU).

Comment: Brian Clozel is there no persistent connection that has to be held on the OS-networking level? Or does that scale very well?

Comment: Yes, but that's not specific to WebFlux nor Netty - it depends on your network infrastructure, OS configuration, network card, etc.

Comment: Brian Clozel well..that definitely makes sense. In the end it passes all those layers too. I guess I'll start looking further into Netty to find clues there though. Any resources to check on how doing it "right"?